# Restore selected value in combobox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have some comboboxes on form, like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ComboId, Model.ComboValues)
```

Also, I have simple action method, which returns recieved model in same view. When change selected item, and submit form, I'll get same page with correct selected value in combobox. But when I click "Back" button in my browser (check this in Chrome 25+, IE 9+), I'll get last selected value.

*For example*, let `ComboValues` contains 2 values: `1` and `2`. Previously, `ComboId = 1`. When I change it to `2` and submit, I'll have form with correct value `2`. But when I click "Back" button in browser, I'll still have combobox with value `2` (but I was hope to see `1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior occurs, because I don't call action, when "Back" in browser. And my page wasn't redrwaing. We can fix this behavior with recalcaluting combobox selected item when page loaded:

```
$(function () {
    $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.ComboId)").val("@Model.ComboId");
}
```

Comment: So your problem is gone?

Comment: @Anar, yes. I just decided to share this problem with community